# How to download data from hidden rows from a table on a web page using bs4 on py3

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to know how I can download the datas from the first table that are contained in hidden row an save that into arrays at the following link:

https://www.diretta.it/giocatore/dybala-paulo/W4myUVXR/

To see them I have to press the button `"show more matches"` that you see in the image.
It is important that the code downloads every number/name in the first match table even the elements in hidden rows that is the focus of the question.
When you press that button the table shows other lines relating to the oldest games of that player.
I used the code you see below and was able to download only the information you see and not the information you get after pressing the button.

```
for record in link.findAll('a', class_ = 'leagueTable__team'):
    linkplayer = record.get('href')
    destlink.append(linkplayer)

for i in range(len(destlink)):
    link_step1 = "https://www.diretta.it"+ destlink[i]+"/rosa/"
    link_team.append(link_step1)
    link_soap1=make_soup(link_step1)
    for record in link_soap1.findAll('div', class_='tableTeam__squadName--playerName'):
    for record1 in record.findAll("a"):
        linkplayer = record1.get('href')
        link_step2=diretta+linkplayer
        players.append(linkplayer)
        link_step2_list.append(link_step2)

for i in range(len(link_step2_list)):
    link_soap2 = make_soup(link_step2_list[i])
    for record in link_soap2.findAll('div', class_='playerTable__date'):
        date = record.get_text()
        print(date)
```

HTML:

```
 <div class = class="profileTable__row profileTable__row--last show-more-last-matches">
<a>Mostra più incontri</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $this = $('.profileTable__row--leagueHeading')
    $this.hide();
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $this.eq(0).show();
       var actualElement = $this.eq(0).attr('data-state');
       for(var i = 1; i < $this.length; i++) {
           if($this.eq(i).attr('data-state') != actualElement) {
               $this.eq(i).show();
               actualElement = $this.eq(i).attr('data-state');
          }
      }
   })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about bs4 but ...

The 'hidden' data isn't actually in the page until you click on the "show more" link.  So you need to use something like selenium to:

1. find the "show more" link
2. click the link
3. Use selenium to find all of the players again

This code will open the page, find the link, and click it:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.diretta.it/giocatore/dybala-paulo/W4myUVXR/')

for link in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a'):
    if "Mostra" in link.text:
        link.click()
```

You need to have the chrome driver installed on your box too..

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: for me I have to execute the script that you see into the div class using the code  in python. In another words I have to press that button using the code in python. But it never worked

Comment: Right, selenium will do that for you.  After selenium opens the page.  Search for the link and call `click()` on the link.

Comment: @TommasoFaedo, check out the update to my answer.  It shows you how to use selenium to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The data is obtained through a new request and getting the result as json. One possibility is making the script do that request and parsing the json object.